# Gradle can't find a package which exists on Gradle Plugin Portal

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` plugin using DLS :

```
plugins {
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.30"
}
```

the plugin exists on Gradle Plugin Portal (check `https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm/1.4.30`), however I get this error:

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.30'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.4.30')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
maven { setUrl("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
        gradlePluginPortal()
```

to `setting.gradle` and using a VPN solved the problem